# Navigation Bar support

Tags: html, css

It will not format correctly, it won't remove the bullets nor will it format the block behind the text.
I'm out of ideas. Is there anyone that can coach me through this, please?
It will not format correctly, it won't remove the bullets nor will it format the block behind the text.
I'm out of ideas. Is there anyone that can coach me through this, please?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;   /* This removes the border around the viewport in old versions of IE */
  width:100%;
  background:#fff;
  min-width:600px;  /* Minimum width of layout - remove line if not required */
      /* The min-width property does not work in old versions of Internet Explorer */
  font-size:90%;
 }
 a {
  color:#369;
 }
 a:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background:#369;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
 h1, h2, h3 {
  margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
  padding:0;
  clear:both;
 }
 p {
  margin:.4em 0 .8em 0;
  padding:0;
 }
 img {
  margin:10px 0 5px;
 }
 #ads {
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 0;
 }
 #ads #mjt {
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:20px;
 }
 #ads .adhere {
  margin:0 10px 10px 0;
 }
 #ads img {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
 }
 
 /* download link */
 .download {
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  padding-top:10px;
 }
 .download a {
  padding:.3em .5em !important;
  margin-right:10px;
  background:#00bd3e;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.5em;
  -moz-border-radius:.3em;
  -webkit-border-radius:.3em;
  border-radius:.3em;
  line-height:2.5em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px  1px 2px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
 }
 .download a:hover {
  background:#5f534f;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
 }

 /* Header styles */
 #header {
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
 }
 #header {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 }
 #header p,
 #header h1,
 #header h2 {
  padding:.4em 15px 0 15px;
  margin:0;
 }
 #header ul {
  clear:left;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  list-style:none;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
  padding:0;
 }
 #header ul li {
  display:inline;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 #header ul li a {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 0 1px;
  padding:3px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#eee;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  left:15px;
  line-height:1.3em;
 }
 #header ul li a:hover {
  background:#369;
  color:#fff;
 }
 #header ul li a.active,
 #header ul li a.active:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 #header ul li a span {
  display:block;
 }
 /* 'widths' sub menu */
 #layoutdims {
  clear:both;
  background:#eee;
  border-top:4px solid #000;
  margin:0;
  padding:6px 15px !important;
  text-align:right;
 }
**.navbar {
 background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}**
 /* column container */
 .colmask {
  position:relative; /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug */
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100%;   /* width of whole page */
  overflow:hidden;  /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
 }
 /* common column settings */
 .colright,
 .colmid,
 .colleft {
  float:left;
  width:100%;   /* width of page */
  position:relative;
 }
 .col1,
 .col2,
 .col3 {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 0 1em 0; /* no left and right padding on columns, we just make them narrower instead 
      only padding top and bottom is included here, make it whatever value you need */
  overflow:hidden;
 }
 /* 3 Column settings */
 .threecol {
  background:#eee;  /* right column background colour */
 }
 .threecol .colmid {
  right:25%;   /* width of the right column */
  background:#fff;  /* center column background colour */
 }
 .threecol .colleft {
  right:50%;   /* width of the middle column */
  background:#f4f4f4; /* left column background colour */
 }
 .threecol .col1 {
  width:46%;   /* width of center column content (column width minus padding on either side) */
  left:102%;   /* 100% plus left padding of center column */
 }
 .threecol .col2 {
  width:21%;   /* Width of left column content (column width minus padding on either side) */
  left:31%;   /* width of (right column) plus (center column left and right padding) plus (left column left padding) */
 }
 .threecol .col3 {
  width:21%;   /* Width of right column content (column width minus padding on either side) */
  left:85%;   /* Please make note of the brackets here:
      (100% - left column width) plus (center column left and right padding) plus (left column left and right padding) plus (right column left padding) */
 }
 /* Footer styles */
 #footer {
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
 }
 #footer p {
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
<head>
    
    </head>
<body>

<div id="header">
 <p><a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/perfect-liquid-layouts">&laquo; Back to the CSS article</a> by <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com">Matthew James Taylor</a></p>
 <h1>The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout (Percentage widths)</h1>
 <h2>No CSS hacks. SEO friendly. No Images. No JavaScript. Cross-browser &amp; iPhone compatible.</h2>
 </div>
 
 <div class="navbar">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://w3schools.com" class="active">Column 1 <span>Holy Grail</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://facebook.com">3 Column <span>Column 2 </span></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://yahoo.com">2 Column <span>Column 3 </span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <p id="layoutdims">Measure columns in: <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm">Pixel widths</a> | <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-ems.htm">Em widths</a> | <strong>Percentage widths</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="colmask threecol">
 <div class="colmid">
  <div class="colleft">
   <div class="col1">
    <!-- Column 1 start -->
    <p class="download"><a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/css-layouts/holy-grail-3-column-liquid-layout-percentage.zip">Download this layout</a> (25kb zip file).</p>
    <h2>Percentage dimensions of the holy grail layout</h2>
    <img src="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column-dimensions.gif" width="350" height="370" alt="Three column layout dimensions" />
    <p>All the dimensions are in percentage widths so the layout adjusts to any screen resolution. Vertical dimensions are not set so they stretch to the height of the content.</p>
    <h3>Maximum column content widths</h3>
    <p>To prevent wide content (like long URLs) from destroying the layout (long content can make the page scroll horizontally) the column content divs are set to overflow:hidden. This chops off any content that is wider than the div. Because of this, it's important to know the maximum widths allowable at common screen resolutions. For example, if you choose 800 x 600 pixels as your minimum compatible resolution what is the widest image that can be safely added to each column before it gets chopped off? Here are the figures:</p>
    <dl>
     <dt><strong>800 x 600</strong></dt>
     <dd>Left &amp; right columns: 162 pixels</dd>
     <dd>Center page: 357 pixels</dd>
     <dt><strong>1024 x 768</strong></dt>
     <dd>Left &amp; right columns: 210 pixels</dd>
     <dd>Center page: 459 pixels</dd>
    </dl>
    <h2>The nested div structure</h2>
    <p>I've colour coded each div so it's easy to see:</p>
    <img src="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column-div-structure.gif" width="350" height="369" alt="Three column layout nested div structure" />
    <p>The header, colmask and footer divs are 100% wide and stacked vertically one after the other. Colmid is inside colmask and colleft is inside colmid. The three column content divs (col1, col2 &amp; col3) are inside colleft. Notice that the main content column (col1) comes before the other columns.</p>
    <!-- Column 1 end -->
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <!-- Column 2 start -->
    <h2>No CSS hacks</h2>
    <p>The CSS used for this layout is 100% valid and hack free. To overcome Internet Explorer's broken box model, no horizontal padding or margins are used in conjunction with a width. Instead, this design uses percentage widths and clever relative positioning.</p>
    <h2>SEO friendly 2-1-3 column ordering</h2>
    <p>The higher up content is in your page code, the more important it is considered by search engine algorithms. To make your website as optimised as possible, your main page content must come before the side columns. This layout does exactly that: The center page comes first, then the left column and finally the right column (see the nested div structure diagram for more info). The columns can also be configured to any other order if required.</p>
    <h2>Full length column background colours</h2>
    <p>In this layout the background colours of each column will always stretch to the length of the longest column. This feature was traditionally only available with table based layouts but now with a little CSS trickery we can do exactly the same with divs. Say goodbye to annoying short columns! You can read my article on <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/equal-height-columns">equal height columns</a> if you want to see how this is done.</p>
    <h2>No Images</h2>
    <p>This layout requires no images. Many CSS website designs need images to colour in the column backgrounds but that is not necessary with this design. Why waste bandwidth and precious HTTP requests when you can do everything in pure CSS and XHTML?</p>
    <h2>No JavaScript</h2>
    <p>JavaScript is not required. Some website layouts rely on JavaScript hacks to resize divs and force elements into place but you won't see any of that nonsense here. The JavaScript at the bottom of this page is just my Google Analytics tracking code, you can remove this when you use the layout.</p>
    <h2>Resizable text compatible</h2>
    <p>This layout is fully compatible with resizable text. Resizable text is important for web accessibility. People who are vision impaired can make the text larger so it's easier for them to read. It is becoming increasingly more important to make your website resizable text compatible because people are expecting higher levels of web accessibility. Apple have made resizing the text on a website simple with the pinch gesture on their multi-touch trackpad. Is your website text-resizing compatible?</p>
    <h2>No Quirks Mode</h2>
    <p>This liquid layout does not require the XML declaration for it to display correctly in older versions of Internet Explorer. This version works without it and is thus never in quirks mode.</p>
    <h2>No IE Conditional Comments</h2>
    <p>Only one stylesheet is used with this layout This means that IE conditional comments are not needed to set extra CSS rules for older versions of Internet Explorer.</p>
    <!-- Column 2 end -->
   </div>
   <div class="col3">
    <!-- Column 3 start -->
    <h2>Browser Compatibility</h2>
    <p>This 3 column liquid Layout has been tested on the following browsers:</p>
    <h3>iPhone &amp; iPod Touch</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Safari</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Mac</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Safari</li>
     <li>Firefox</li>
     <li>Opera 9.25</li>
     <li>Netscape 9.0.0.5 &amp; 7.1</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Windows</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Firefox 1.5, 2 &amp; 3</li>
     <li>Safari</li>
     <li>Opera 8.1 &amp; 9</li>
     <li>Google Chrome</li>
     <li>Explorer 5.5, 6 &amp; 7</li>
     <li>Netscape 8</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Valid XHTML strict markup</h2>
    <p>The HTML in this layout validates as XHTML 1.0 strict.</p>
    <h2>This layout is FREE for anyone to use</h2>
    <p>That's right, you don't have to pay anything. If you are feeling generous however, link back to this page so other people can find and use this layout too.</p>
    <p><a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/css-layouts/holy-grail-3-column-liquid-layout-percentage.zip">Download this layout</a> (25kb zip file).</p>
    <h2>Centered menus compatible</h2>
    <p>This layout is fully compatible with my <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/css-centred-menus">centered menus</a>.</p>
    <!-- Column 3 end -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>This page uses the <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm">Perfect 'Holy Grail' 3 Column Liquid Layout</a> by <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com">Matthew James Taylor</a>. View more <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/website-layout-examples">website layouts</a> and <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/web-design-tips">web design tips</a>.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

remove the bullets nor add a block behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
list-style: none;
```

in your CSS to set ALL ul elements to not have bullet points use the following

```
ul{ 
   list-style: none !important;
}
```

elements in your html, will stop you from having the bullet points, you have done this to your specific header UL but not to any subsequent ones.

Comment: <ul style="list-style: none;"> foo </ul> will work

in your css this will work for the entire site

ul{
    list-style: none !important; 
}

Comment: But I need the html and the css separated.

Comment: so in the CSS use......... ul { list-style: none !Important; } i will update my answer, one second

Comment: That is fine, it's a learning curve, see my updated answer :)

Comment: So, how does it know where to apply this change to? My goal is to add no style to the Navigation bar. Why doesn't it have .nav ul{ 
   list-style: none !important;
}

Comment: when I run the code snippet there does not appear to be any dot points in the header, can you write out the line where they are appearing for you ? the code I gave you will wipe out all of the list style attributes (set it to none) across the whole doc

Comment: I added that piece of code to my css and it did not update anything. :(

Comment: make sure to do a hard refresh / empty cache, CTRL+SHIFT+R does it on windows, COMMAND+SHIFT+R does it on mac, alternatively in chrome, with the inspect window open, hold down on the refresh button, and it will come up with a menu, select hard reload and empty cache

Comment: Still nothing m8. I'm using Brackets

Comment: bulletpoints, the dots next to the list items you want to get rid of

Comment: Column 1 Holy Grail
3 Column Column 2
2 Column Column 3

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/n18i17Mr.png

I think this is a brackets issue, open up your code in a browser, seems to look fine in chrome to me

Comment: ugh. I even tried opening it in safari... but if I changed the color of the background it would show... I don't understand this stuff m8

Comment: try it with chrome, at least that way you can verify if it is a code problem, or a browser compatibility problem

Comment: Im using chrome as my default browser m8

Comment: I can't get your problem to replicate, try making a JS fiddle and I will debug :)

Comment: I dont know much Javascript.

Comment: js fiddle or codepen allow you to copy and paste your code online for people to debug, do a quick search on it